# How login in basecamp account without a browser?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, basecamp

I'm using Python and trying to login to basecamp to consume their API but  i'm having some trouble with OAuth2 authentication... 
How do I login without interacting with browser? I'm making a post request but it returns a 422 message...
I checked out the headers and they seem ok. I'm confused and dont know where the mistake is.

Comment: Im using python to do the requests

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 requires that the user authorizes the integration to access her/his account. This is done through a web page in which basecamp.com will display some HTML including a button. For this to work, the user must be logged in using the web form at https://launchpad.37signals.com/signin.

I've implemented that in Javascript: https://gitlab.petton.fr/basecampel/libbasecampel/blob/v0.2.0/proxy/src/oauth.js. The function at line 20 opens the system's default web browser in which the user is supposed to login if he/she is not logged in already.